# RVM - Ruby integration was extracted to a separate gem (`remove $LOAD_PATH.unshift`)

Tags: apache2, rvm, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-3-upgrade, load-path

I was upgrading to Rails 3.2.6 (ruby 1.9.3-p194) and installing RVM on Debian and using Apache2 server (2.2.19).

I used these very nice instructions: http://dalibornasevic.com/posts/21-rvm-and-passenger-setup-for-rails-2-and-rails-3-apps/

The Apache server configuration **/etc/apache2/apache2.conf** includes:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails326/gems/passenger-3.0.13/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails326/gems/passenger-3.0.13
PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails326/ruby
```

When I have set everything up (and got rid of tons of errormessages :) the following error message from passenger appears:

#### RVM - Ruby integration was extracted to a separate gem, it should be installed by default with RVM, remove the `$LOAD_PATH.unshift` line and all should be fine again.

By commenting out `$LOAD_PATH.unshift` in MyApp/config/setup_load_paths.rb this error goes away and instead I get a 500 error, Internal Server Error.

**/etc/log/apache2/error.log:**

```
[ pid=5262 thr=3075372800 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:862 time=2012-07-10 12:33:41.475 ]: Unexpected error in mod_passenger: Cannot spawn application '/var/www/MyApp': The spawn server has exited unexpectedly.
  Backtrace:
     in 'virtual Passenger::SessionPtr Passenger::ApplicationPool::Client::get(const Passenger::PoolOptions&)' (Client.h:742)
     in 'Passenger::SessionPtr Hooks::getSession(const Passenger::PoolOptions&)' (Hooks.cpp:294)
     in 'int Hooks::handleRequest(request_rec*)' (Hooks.cpp:563)
```

I would be very pleased if anyone could give me a clue on this problem.
Thank you very much.
Íris